# Can't Download Wubi

Tags: wubi, downloads

I want to download Ubuntu with WUBI but, the WUBI download page redirects [here](http://ftp.linux.org.tr/ubuntu-releases//precise/wubi.exe) and this page doesn't load anymore.

Comment: The link proposed in the question is currently up.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download *just* WUBI, you can do that [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer).  The Live CD come's with WUBI as well.

This works in the United States, it might not work in other Countries.